# Question that asking for a vote

Tags: discussion, support

Someone make a question about [`AmazonWebServiceClient`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052214/amazonwebserviceclient-generating-throttling-exceptions-rate-exceeded-thrott) bug, but he didn't even explain how the bug occurred or what the bug cause and in the end of the question he/her asking for a vote up.

Then he post an answer to his question and asking for a vote up again.

How should I deal with this user? What kind of action do I need to do?

Comment: Well I reacted, as I think we should deal with such stuff.

Comment: You've called for _meta effect_ actually about this question. It would be a fair gesture to inform the OP about it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Should I comment into OP question that the question his/her asked  is linked to this discussion?

Comment: _"Should I comment to OP question that the question his/her asked is linked to this discussion?"_ That's exactly what I'm proposing. It's just fair to do so, if you're going to discuss about a particular question (linked) here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I don't think the major point is the OP was asking for upvotes (This is certainly not encouraged, and easily turns into the opposite behavior of visitors. I have just edited that irrelevant stuff out).

The question itself is very unclear (and announcing an answer doesn't help much, edited out that as well).

Similarly for the self answered answer (regarding asking for upvotes at least). The answer doesn't really match what was(n't) asked in the question, or makes an attempt to give a prove or explanation why this should be the ***magic bullet*** to deal with the Amazon API.

I've downvoted question and answer, and voted to close the question as being unclear.
I've also left a comment on the answer, that I've doubts it solves what's promised.

These were the actions I have taken on that particular question. You might not be able to take all of these actions yourself, because of your current reputation restrictions. Though you're able to edit and flag questions and answers in a similar manner.